# how to get the left character in stream?

Tags: c, stream, getchar

Here is the function definition of get_line which:-

1. skip whitespaces in the begining.
2. stop at first white space.
3. stop at first newline character and place it in the array.
4. leave behind character if it does not have space available.

---

```
int get_line (char* ch, int n)
{

    if ( n <= 0)
        return 0;

    char c;

    while ( isspace(c = getchar()));
    int i = 0;

    do {
        ch[i++] = c;
        if ( i == n)
            break;
    }while ( ! isspace(c = getchar()));

    if ( c == '\n')
        ch[i++] = '\n';

    ch[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main()
{

    char array[5];

    get_line(array, 4);
    printf("%s", array);

    char c;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        printf("\n%c", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when i enter more characters then the size and try to print the remaining character in main using the last while loop, it prints weird characters and not printing the remaining characters in the stream as required by the fourth specification of the function. Please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Fyi, you may want to check the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of  `(c = getchar() != '\n'`)`. Just saying...

Comment: @WhozCraig ya it worked

Comment: @WhozCraig can you explain a bit

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`, as much as `printf` takes an `int` for `%c`. Enable compiler warnings. After chainging, also catch `EOF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you ran afoul of [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

In this statement:

```
while ( c = getchar() != '\n'){
```

The comparison operator `!=` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So `getchar() != '\n'` is evaluated first and will be either `1` or `0` since it is a boolean expression.

Assuming the next character is not a newline, the value will be `1`.  Then `c = 1` is evaluated and the loop continues by printing the value `1` as a char.  When a newline is found, `getchar() != '\n'` evaluates to `0`, then `c = 0` is evaluated and the loop exits.

You need to add parenthesis here to get the intended order of operations:

```
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n'){
```

Answer (score 2):

WhozCraig pointed out that your problem is the operator precedence. This is what happens:

```
while ( c = getchar() != '\n'){
    printf("\n%c", c);
}
```

In the condition expression of your `while` statement, first the experssion `getchar() != '\n'` is evaluated. Then the result of this is assigned to `c`. The expression yields the result of the comparission of the call to `getchar()`, which retrieves the next character, with the constant character value `'\n'`.

Depending on how the comparisson operator `!=` is implemented, you can get weird characters. Note that Boolean 'true' in C is defined as non-zero and Boolean 'false' as zero. For example, it would be perfectly legal for the compiler to subtract the byte value of `\n` from the `'getchar()` result and test for non-zero. In assembler this would look something like:

```
call   getchar
sub    ax, 0x0d    ' getchar result in ax; subtract \n from it
mov    c, ax       ' move result of subtraction to variable c
jz     end_loop    ' end loop if zero (= equal)
```